# Intermittent TypeError: Failed to fetch in Blazor WASM .Net7

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WASM site that is deployed 20-30 times for various customers. They run independently but on the same servers. All run the same version of code, on their own subdomains with their own separate databases

The sites work fine, and speed is fine, and the responses are fine. Everything is great, except once in a while I get these "Failed to Fetch" errors and I can't for the life of me reproduce them.

The wisdom of the Internet is to add a wide-open net CORS policy, but that feels like it's a solution for people who get the issue on every API call. I get the issue only once every 1000.

No users have complained about it, and the only time I've ever managed to hit it it looks like the page just hung, so they must just refresh and go about their day.

It happens across all browser types and various different API endpoints. On the back end, I see no issues (timeouts, event viewer bugs, etc.). Has anyone else come across this before?

As I move more and more customers onto the platform I'm getting a bit worried this issue will cascade and I'll be in real trouble!

**The exception:**

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: TypeError: Failed to fetch ---> TypeError: Failed to fetch Exception_EndOfInnerExceptionStack 
at System.Net.Http.BrowserHttpInterop.d__13`1[[System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.JSObject, System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]].MoveNext() 
at System.Net.Http.BrowserHttpHandler.CallFetch(HttpRequestMessage , CancellationToken , Nullable`1 ) at System.Net.Http.BrowserHttpHandler.g__Impl|55_0(HttpRequestMessage , CancellationToken , Nullable`1 ) 
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage , HttpCompletionOption , CancellationTokenSource , Boolean , CancellationTokenSource , CancellationToken ) at MySite.Client.d__9`1[[MyResponseDto]].MoveNext()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm a bit wary about adding a CORs policy that just says `AllowedEverything()` as it feels a bit risky.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, This error was thrown whenever a user lost internet connection and performed an action that required a server call.

I am handling errors globally using `CustomErrorBoundary` where I handled this error and showed a suitable message.

I hope this helps.